# 'SearchView.QueryTextSubmitEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no accessible extension method 'Query'

Tags: xamarin.android, searchview

I am getting following error after upgrading

1. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
2. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView

> Error :- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'SearchView.QueryTextSubmitEventArgs' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Query' and no accessible extension method 'Query'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'SearchView.QueryTextSubmitEventArgs' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code

```
 private void SearchView_QueryTextSubmit(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextSubmitEventArgs e)
    {
        ListElement element = Page.Elements.PrimaryElement as ListElement;
        SearchView searchView = sender as SearchView;

        if (element != null && searchView != null)
        {
            this.View.RequestFocus();
            InputMethodManager inputManager = this.View.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            inputManager.ToggleSoftInput(0, 0);
            element.ListData.SearchTerm = e.Query;
        }
    }
```

Here in the last line `e.Query` causes the issue. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does it work now ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences between V4 and V7 .

The property **e.Query** had been changed as **e.NewText** .As we can seen from the source code

```
public class QueryTextSubmitEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public QueryTextSubmitEventArgs(bool handled, string newText);

  public bool Handled { get; set; }
  public string NewText { get; }
}
```